# Cannot add prebuilt apk to AOSP

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I am trying to add a prebuilt apk to an A13 AOSP build but the build process throws an error.

I have tried the following:

Created the directory device/company/product/myapp.

Copied my apk and Android.mk file under the "myapp" directory.

Added following line to product.mk:

$(call inherit-product-if-exists, device/company/product/myapp/Android.mk)

PRODUCT_PACKAGES += myapp

Triggered a full AOSP build using make.

However, I get the following error:

build/make/core/app_prebuilt_internal.mk:238: error: writing to readonly directory: "/APPS/myapp_intermediates/package.apk"

Update:
Android.mk file contents:
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_MODULE := myapp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myapp.apk

LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS

LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .apk

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_VENDOR)/priv-app

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.